# Stack Overflow search results disappearing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, search

A few days ago, I noticed that when searching on SO, results flash for less than a second, and then disappear. Using both Firefox's and Chrome's latest stable builds on Windows XP causes same result.

Comment: Just tried search and it seems fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing all the search results share a tag in your Ignored Tags list with your preference set to "hide".

Try doing the search while logged out, or from another web browser, to confirm this.

Or you can disable hiding ignored tags, obviously.

Comment: That's absolutely correct. BUT I'm not sure if search results should respect this 'hide' setting at all.

Comment: How does this behave on your own questions or questions that I answer?   If I create a question/answer and someone tags it with one of my ignored tags, can I still see it?   I imagine I can see it in my profile, but what about in the regular stack?    WEIRD.

Comment: I stumbled on this behaviour today. Wouldn't it be better to mention explicitly that the results are all hidden because of ignored tags ? Much like a real empty earch result displays an information about it.