# ASP.NET questions don't display when logged in to stackoverflow

Tags: support, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blank page on search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53015/blank-page-on-search)

When I am logged in to stackoverflow.com and search for [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net), none of the questions show up even though the pagination is there and I see "81,752 questions tagged".

[image: logged in]

When I am logged out, the questions do show up.

[image: logged out]

It is happening on Chrome, Firefox, and IE9. Other searches, like CSS, work fine whether I am logged in or out.

Is something wonky happening on your end or is fate telling me I should not take that asp.net job?

Comment: Did not reproduce locally (IE8). Maybe it *is* a sign.

Comment: Do you have the [tag:asp.net] tag in your list of ignored tags, and have the "hide ignored tags" preference checked? (This may answer your question about taking the job, too...)

Comment: This has come up a few times (though I don't see the dupes in the Related section) and @Tim is spot on, it's been an ignored tag basically every time

Comment: Shoot - egg on my face - I did have that tag on ignore. I forgot all about that feature.  Maybe there needs to be a banner that says "Hey - Dummy - You are searching for a tag that you are ignoring!" or maybe "81,752 questions tagged but you can't see any of them because you are ignoring that tag!"

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53015/blank-page-on-search/53017#53017 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97396/results-on-search-page-disappear-after-page-load http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/bug-in-stackoverflow-com-not-showing-15-results http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25792/stackoverflow-search-results-disappearing

Comment: Related feature requests: [Warning for when no questions are shown due to ignored tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74304) [Don't hide questions when browsing an ignored tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36857) (and some others)