# Bug searching with keywords "java beginner"

Tags: support, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stackoverflow search results disappearing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25792/stackoverflow-search-results-disappearing)

I'm starting school in a month and one of my courses has me using Java.  Wanting to get a head start searching for some books to read on my iPad at my [favorite site ever](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) and I got a weird error when I used the keywords "java" and "beginner".  **The search results would show up while the page was loading but after the browser was through parsing the results would disappear.**

I thought it might have been a fluke, so I cleared my cache, cookies, etc.  Still didn't work.  Hopped over to the Mac to post the bug and figured should check on it too.  Well, I got the same weird error on the Mac.

I was able to replicate this error on:

- iPad 1 WiFi 64gb running up-to-date Safari
- Mac OS X 10.6 running up-to-date Chrome

I was also able to get a screenshot of the error with the iPad.

Here [it is during the load](http://s93.photobucket.com/albums/l42/1234_038/?action=view&current=IMG_0167.png).

And [here it is after](http://s93.photobucket.com/albums/l42/1234_038/?action=view&current=IMG_0168.png).

Thanks for the awesome site(s)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've ignored the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag and selected the `hide ignore tag` in your preferences.

Either unignore the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag or unselect the preference in your profile under the `prefs` tab to see those questions.

Comment: Of course, I feel retarded.  The java tag was down at the bottom and missed my cursory examination.